# Swap column with condition in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have 4 columns in my data file, Column 1 is the chr number and second column is the start site and third is the end site.The fourth column is the strand + or -. Now if the 4th column is the negative strand i want to swap the column 3 with column 2 but for + strand i want no change.

```
Chr1 94847  3737474  +
Chr1 27374  3948475  +
Chr1 93947  9283736  -
```

So the first two rows are good, but for the third row i want to swap column 2 with column 3, as in the 4th column the strand in -.

I tried this code but the system generates an error with & operand...

```
cat hg-19_promoter_knownGene.filtered.bed | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { if ($4 == "+") {print $1,$2,$3} & if ($4 == "-") { print $1,$3,$2 }}'  > hg-19_promoter_knownGene.filter3.bed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, chnage the "&" to ";".

This should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { if ($4 == "+") {print $1,$2,$3} ; if ($4 == "-") { print $1,$3,$2 }}'
```